# Erlang compile error

Tags: compilation, erlang

Windows XP, Erlang R13B02 (erts-5.7.3)

Today werl desn't want compile any erlang file

c(binm).
** exception error: undefined function compile:file/2
     in function  c:c/2

Yesterday all work.

P.S install R14B03, can't compile again

Comment: “P.S install R14B03, can't compile again” - Could you please re-phrase that sentence. I don't understand it.

Comment: Presumably he means that he made a fresh install but still got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very odd error. Have you by accident deleted the compile.beam file from your OTP installation? A re-installation of R13B02 might solve it, if you don't want to change the OTP version.

But if you don't need to use R13B02 for any particular reason, I recommend taking the opportunity to uninstall it and install the latest version (R14B03) instead (http://www.erlang.org/download.html). There have been many improvements, in particular regarding type specifications.

Comment: Ok, I install R14B03, can't compile again, maybe reinstall windows?

Comment: If you still get the same error, you have probably somehow created another compile.beam file that gets loaded instead of the system module. Do "code:which(compile)." and see if it points to the proper OTP module or one of your modules somewhere.

Comment: @egorrrr: You don't need to re-install windows. OTP does not need to be installed in any particular path, so you could have n installations at the same time.

Comment: thank you, I have deleted compile.beam from (code:which(compile).) and all compiled

Answer (score 0):

What does `io:format("~p~n", [code:get_path()]).` print?  It should contain a directory like `somepath/lib/compiler-4.7.2/ebin`. Check that that directory actually exists, and that it contains the file `compile.beam`.